# Empty GameObject not deactivating

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

everyone.

Basically, I have a prefab with a canvas and an empty GameObject. This GameObject, PlayAd, contains its own canvas and a button to play ads and let the users skip a level. PlayAd's button is covering the other canvas's continue button, which is only supposed to be accessible if the user passes a level. All my script is supposed to do is deactivate PlayAd on trigger enter so the users can get to the continue button. However, it never goes away after I reach the trigger to cause this. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewLevScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PlayAd;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        PlayAd = GameObject.Find("PlayAd");
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Platyer")
        {
            PlayAd.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (other.tag == "Platyer") ... is it supposed to be Player or Platyer?

Comment: Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error are off-topic for Stack Overflow. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. See [ask] for more information. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score -1):

Boy, do I feel dumb... I had to remove the "t". It works now.